# prove A is similar to a diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If the $n\times n$ square matrix $A$ satisfy $\operatorname{rank(A+3E)}+\operatorname{rank(A-3E)}=n$, $E$ is the identity matrix , prove A is similar to a diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n \}$ where $x_i=3$ or $-3$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

I have been told to get this by discussing the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=3$ and $\lambda=-3$ . But I am not familiar with the properties of  geometric multiplicity. Any more elementary method to get the point?

Comment: What is $E$? The identity matrix?

Comment: Yep, I'll edit it.

Comment: The geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ and $A$ is the dimension of $\ker(A-\lambda E)$. It is the amount of linear independet eigenvectors you may find.

Answer (score 1):

From $\operatorname{rank}(A+3E)+\operatorname{rank}(A-3E)=n$ and the nullity-rank theorem we get

$n= \dim (\ker(A+3E))+\dim (\ker(A-3E))$. Hence, if $ \mathbb K= \mathbb R$ or$= \mathbb C$:

$\mathbb K^n= \ker(A+3E) \oplus \ker(A-3E).$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $diag(3,\dots 3, -3, \dots, -3)$, then there are vectors $b_1,\dots, b_k,c_1,\dots,c_l$ which form a basis such that $A b_i = 3b_i$ and $Ac_i = -3c_i$. Those vectors are *eigenvectors*. So you have to assert that there are enough of those vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}\DeclareMathOperator{\dim}{dim} \dim(\Ker(A+3E))=n-\operatorname{rank}(A+3E)$ and $\dim(\Ker(A-3E))=$ $n-\operatorname{rank}(A-3E)$, we have 
$$\dim (\Ker(A-3E))+\dim(\Ker(A+3E))=n.$$
The subspaces $\Ker(A-3E)$ and $\Ker(A+3E)$ intersect only at $0$ and their dimensions add up to $n$. So we can choose a basis $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v_1,\ldots, v_k$ is a basis for $\Ker(A-3E)$ and $v_{k+1},\ldots, v_n$ is a basis for $\Ker(A+3E)$. Then the matrix of $A$ in this basis is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to $3$ or $-3$.